# HTML, JS basic script not working on Google Chrome but works on Mozilla and Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, html

first of all, I think I need to give you some background to the problem. I have 1 lecture of JS experience and I a got minimal experience in HTML. I need to create a basic site with one simple JS script. I chose a simple voting system. You have for example 2 resturants and you can give your feedback about any on them (1-5 vote). Site shows average of votes and number of votes for particular restaurant. Everything works perfectly fine on Mozilla Firefox and Microsoft Edge but doesn't work at all on Google Chrome and I don't know what might be the problem. Below you can find a frame for the voting system that I would like to implement into my site. Originally I wrote this code in my native language for the transparency with my "teammates" and this is a version I created just for this question. If anything is not clear feel free to ask.

Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var votesSum = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
        var numVotes = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
        var averageVotes = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
        function average(clicked_value, sent_id)
        {
            var id = parseFloat(sent_id[0]);
            var averageOutput = "average" + id;
            var numVotesOutput = "numVotes" + id;

            numVotes[id - 1] += 1;
            votesSum[id - 1] += parseFloat(clicked_value);
            var average = (votesSum[id - 1] / numVotes[id - 1]).toFixed(2);
            averageVotes[id - 1] = average
            document.getElementById(numVotesOutput).value = numVotes[id - 1];
            document.getElementById(averageOutput).value = averageVotes[id - 1];
        }

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="vote1">
        Restaurant X
        <select >
            <option id="1a" value="1" onclick="average(this.value,this.id)">1</option>
            <option id="1b" value="2" onclick="average(this.value,this.id)">2</option>
            <option id="1c" value="3" onclick="average(this.value,this.id)">3</option>
            <option id="1d" value="4" onclick="average(this.value,this.id)">4</option>
            <option id="1e" value="5" onclick="average(this.value,this.id)">5</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        Average  <input id="average1" value="0" size="4" readonly />
        <br />
        Number of votes  <input id="numVotes1" value="0" readonly size="4" />
    </div>


    <div class="vote2">
        Restaurant Y
        <select>
            <option id="2a" value="1" onclick="average(this.value,this.id)">1</option>
            <option id="2b" value="2" onclick="average(this.value,this.id)">2</option>
            <option id="2c" value="3" onclick="average(this.value,this.id)">3</option>
            <option id="2d" value="4" onclick="average(this.value,this.id)">4</option>
            <option id="2e" value="5" onclick="average(this.value,this.id)">5</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        Average  <input id="average2" value="0" size="4" readonly />
        <br />
        Number of Votes  <input id="numVotes2" value="0" readonly size="4" />
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Everything works perfectly fine on Mozilla Firefox and Microsoft Edge but doesn't work at all on Google Chrome? What doesn't work?

Comment: Check your console in chrome for any errors. Inspect > Console.

Comment: The script, I can open a site from a html file and just vote and it counts votes and average. On chrome it doesnt do anything I can vote but it doesnt count. I tried some alerts to check if the script they didnt pop up, it seems to not be working at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set the `onclick` on the option, instead of the select-element.

The event should be on the select-element, and should probably be `onchange` instead, so that it works even if the value is changed via keyboard or touch.

Example:

```
<select data-restaurant="1" onchange="average(this.value, this.dataset.restaurant)">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Setting the restaurant id as a data-attribute.

If you want to use buttons instead:

```
<div class="vote1">
    Restaurant X
    <button value="1" name="1" onclick="average(this.value, this.name)">1</button>
    <button value="2" name="1" onclick="average(this.value, this.name)">2</button>
    <button value="3" name="1" onclick="average(this.value, this.name)">3</button>
    <button value="4" name="1" onclick="average(this.value, this.name)">4</button>
    <button value="5" name="1" onclick="average(this.value, this.name)">5</button>
    <br />
    Average <input id="average1" value="0" size="4" readonly />
    <br />
    Number of votes <input id="numVotes1" value="0" readonly size="4" />
</div>
```

Using buttons solves the problem with multiple votes with the same value.

Comment: "onchange" seems to solve the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: One problem with that solution is that if the 1st vote is the same as default it wont count because the value doesnt change  so I added this line

<option value="" selected disabled hidden>Vote</option>

Comment: The problem with select and onchange is that you only get the value if it was changed. And you can't vote the same value twice in a row. There are several different solutions: for example, instead of a select, add 5 buttons. then you can vote any value at any time.

Comment: @PiotrWcisło Can you use buttons instead?

Comment: Yea I might change it to buttons just to be safe